# Cannot start OSX app exported from XCode from Finder

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an OSX application which I want to export with XCode's Organizer as .app package. The package is generated successfully but it cannot be started directly. However I can start the executable inside the package directly from the Terminal. There are no errors in the Terminal, the app works as expected. The app is not signed during build process and not resigned during export. Console shows no crashes or errors. XCode version 4.6.3. OSX version 10.8.4.

So why is the .app package cannot be executed directly by a double-click? I'm sure it worked before.

Comment: The most common cause for this kind of problem is that an assumption has been made about the initial working directory. So if you are using a relative path to find some kind of data file or other resource then it may well fail in different launch scenarios, where the initial working directory differs.

Comment: Does `Console.app` show any errors?

Comment: No, Console.app shows nothing